# Save errors in database while inserting data into database via excel sheet in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

In my project, we are uploading information in database via xls sheet for that we are using gem 'roo' and gem 'axlsx_rails'. Now we need to store the errors that we get while uploading information in database.

We cannot upload code as there are lot of things inter-related to uploading data via excel in project.

Please suggest a ways or gem to do this in rails 5. We are using mysql database.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please review the [how to ask a good question page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question is too broad / opinion based. You'll typically want to provide code and let everyone know what you've tried so far.

Comment: Okay. I will try to make my question more clear. Thanks